# How to Update Label text in tkinter subframe class

Tags: tkinter

I am having problems with updating Label Text via class function call through button command. I have divided my root frame in to five sub frames. Once button command function invoked and ask user for input files. User input file path displayed in root frame not the subframe from where function is invoked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsAKn.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana', 10)

def donothing():
    print('Do Nothing')


class rootframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "ABC")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

        for F in (StartPage, graph, piano):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        sidebar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=250, height=780,
                        borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
        statusbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=30,
                          borderwidth=2, relief="ridge")
        toolbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=30,
                        borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
        helpbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=150,
                        borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
        mainframe = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=550,
                          borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
        sidebar.pack(side='left', anchor='sw')
        statusbar.pack(side='bottom', anchor='center')
        toolbar.pack(fill=X, side='top', anchor='center')
        helpbar.pack(side='bottom', anchor='center')
        mainframe.pack(side='top', anchor='center')

        label = tk.Label(toolbar, text='Start Page', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(side='left', anchor='sw', expand=True)

        button2 = ttk.Button(toolbar, text='File Merge Tool',
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(piano))
        button2.pack(side='left', expand=True)
        button3 = ttk.Button(toolbar, text='Graph Page',
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(graph))
        button3.pack(side='left', expand=True)


class piano(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = parent
        filename = " "
        sidebar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=250, height=780, borderwidth=2,
                    relief='ridge')
        statusbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=30,
                      borderwidth=2, relief="ridge")
        toolbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=30, borderwidth=2,
                    relief='ridge')
        helpbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=150,
                    borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
        mainframe = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=550,
                      borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")

        sidebar.pack(side='left', anchor='sw')
        statusbar.pack(side='bottom', anchor='center')
        toolbar.pack(fill=X, side='top', anchor='center')
        helpbar.pack(side='bottom', anchor='center')
        mainframe.pack(side='top', anchor='center')

        button2 = ttk.Button(toolbar, text='HOME',
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.pack(side='right', anchor='nw', expand=True)

        label = tk.Label(mainframe, text='File Merge', font=36)
        label.place(x=510, y=10)

        label1 = tk.Label(mainframe, text='file1', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.place(x=0, y=60)
        inp1 = ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Browse',
                      command=lambda: piano.readfile())
        inp1.place(x=800, y=60)
        pathlabel = Label(mainframe, background='white', width=80, relief='sunken',
                      borderwidth=4)
        pathlabel.place(x=220, y=60)
        pathlabel.config(text=filename)

        label2 = tk.Label(mainframe, text='file2', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.place(x=0, y=80)
        inp2 = ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Browse',
                      command=lambda: piano.readfile())
        inp2.place(x=800, y=80)
        pathlabel1 = Label(mainframe, background='white', width=80, relief='sunken',
                       borderwidth=4)
        pathlabel1.place(x=220, y=80)
        pathlabel1.config(text=filename)

    def readfile():
        filename = fd.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("TXT Files", "*.txt")])
        pathlabel = Label(background='white', width=80, relief='sunken',
                          borderwidth=4)
        pathlabel.place(x=220, y=60)
        pathlabel.config(text=filename)


class graph(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='Graph', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Back to Home',
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


app = rootframe()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `pathlabel` to `self.pathlabel`, and have your function `readfile` update the text of `pathlabel` instead of creating a new widget every time.

```
class piano(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = parent
        filename=" "
        sidebar =  Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke',width=250, height=780,borderwidth=2,relief='ridge')
        statusbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke',width=1280, height=30,borderwidth=2, relief="ridge")
        toolbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=30,borderwidth=2,relief='ridge')
        helpbar = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=150,borderwidth=2,relief='ridge')
        mainframe = Frame(self, bg='whitesmoke', width=1280, height=550,borderwidth=2,relief="sunken")

        sidebar.pack(side='left',anchor='sw')
        statusbar.pack(side='bottom',anchor='center')
        toolbar.pack(fill=X,side='top',anchor='center')
        helpbar.pack(side='bottom',anchor='center')
        mainframe.pack(side='top',anchor='center')

        button2=ttk.Button(toolbar,text='HOME',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.pack(side='right',anchor='nw',expand=True)

        label=tk.Label(mainframe,text='File Merge',font=36)
        label.place(x=510,y=10)


        label1=tk.Label(mainframe,text='file1',font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.place(x=0,y=60)
        inp1=ttk.Button(mainframe,text='Browse',command=lambda: self.readfile(self.pathlabel))
        inp1.place(x=800,y=60)
        self.pathlabel = Label(mainframe,background='white',width=80,relief='sunken',borderwidth=4)
        self.pathlabel.place(x=220,y=60)
        self.pathlabel.config(text=filename)

        label2=tk.Label(mainframe,text='file2',font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.place(x=0,y=80)
        inp2=ttk.Button(mainframe,text='Browse',command=lambda: self.readfile(self.pathlabel1))
        inp2.place(x=800,y=80)
        self.pathlabel1 = Label(mainframe,background='white',width=80,relief='sunken',borderwidth=4)
        self.pathlabel1.place(x=220,y=80)
        self.pathlabel1.config(text=filename)

    def readfile(self,path_entry):
        filename = fd.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("TXT Files", "*.txt")])
        path_entry.config(text=filename)
```

Comment: i have made changes in code but its still not working output is same.

Comment: I guess a simplified version wasn't detailed enough. Heres the whole piano class that works.